# How can I convert a dataset to an S3 or S4 object and still be able to analyze the data based on the rows?

Tags: r, oop

Full disclosure, this is a homework assignment. I'm not looking for an answer, but as you can tell from my having to ask this question in the first place 1) I am very new to R, and 2) the professor does not exactly teach to the lowest common denominator.

My task is to create a class (`LongitudinalData`) for a dataset consisting of `id`, visit, `timepoint`, `room`, and `value` columns, as well as subject, visit, and room classes and corresponding methods. The end goal is to be able to produce a package that allows the following code to run:

```
library(readr)
library(magrittr)
## Load any other packages that you may need to execute your code
data <- read_csv("data/MIE.csv")
x <- make_LD(data)
print(class(x))
[1] "LongitudinalData"
print(x)
Longitudinal dataset with 10 subjects
## Subject 10 doesn't exist
out <- subject(x, 10)
print(out)
NULL
out <- subject(x, 14)
print(out)
Subject ID: 14
out <- subject(x, 54) %>% summary
print(out)
ID: 54
10 NA NA 21 NA 13.450946 3 2 4.193721 3.779225
out <- subject(x, 14) %>% summary
print(out)
ID: 14
1 2 3
0  4.786592
1  3.401442
2 18.583635
      NA     2.75000
8.426549          NA
      NA    22.55069
visit  bedroom       den living room
visit   bedroom family  room living room
            office
2.792601 13.255475
      NA  4.533921
      NA        NA
out <- subject(x, 44) %>% visit(0) %>% room("bedroom")
print(out)
ID: 44
Visit: 0
Room: bedroom
## Show a summary of the pollutant values
out <- subject(x, 44) %>% visit(0) %>% room("bedroom") %>% summary
print(out)
ID: 44
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
    8.0    30.0    51.0    88.8    80.0   911.0
out <- subject(x, 44) %>% visit(1) %>% room("living room") %>% summary
print(out)
 ID: 44
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
 2.75   14.00   24.00   41.37   37.00 1607.00
```

I gave it the old college try, but I fear that I'm just writing code that 
gives the desired output, but doesn't perform the correct function. I have:

```
MIE <- read_csv("MIE.csv")
make_LD <- function(a) {   
  structure(list(subject = a$id, visit = a$visit, room = a$room, value = 
a$value, timepoint = a$timepoint), class = "LongitudinalData")
}
length.LongitudinalData <- function(a) {
  b <- unique(a$subject) %>%
    length
  b
}
x <- make_LD(MIE)
print(class(x))
subject <- function(a, id) {
  structure(list(subject = a$id), class = "subject")
  if(id %in% a$subject) {
    paste("Subject ID:", id)
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}
summary.LongitudinalData <- function(a, id) {
  print(subject(a, id))

}
out <- subject(x, 10)
print(out)
out <- subject(x, 14)
print(out)
```

Any help on any section would be greatly appreciated, but I think the first place I'm getting hung up is right when I create the LongitudinalData class. It returns what appears to be a list of all the ids followed by a list of all the visits, and so on. I was able to force that through for the first few parts of the desired code, but I feel like I need a way to retain the rows of the original dataset so that all the values in it are retained together so I can summarize them in the later parts.

I understand that for homework questions it's expected that you walk through some of your thought process, so one of my failed attempts contained something along these lines:

```
for(i in 1:length(MIE$id) {
apply(MIE, 1, structure, list(subject = MIE$id[i], visit = MIE$visit[i], 
room = MIE$room[i], value = MIE$value[i], timepoint = MIE$timepoint[i]), 
class = "LongitudinalData")
}
```

I hoped that I could create an object for each row (I honestly don't know if 
that would have helped me accomplish the task, but it made more sense to me than distinct lists of values from each column).

I also tried creating an S4 object, and I ran into the same problem.

```
MIE <- read_csv("MIE.csv")
make_LD <- function(a) {
  setClass("LongitudinalData", slots = list(subject = "numeric", visit = "numeric", room = "character", timepoint = "numeric", value = "numeric"))
  new("LongitudinalData", subject = MIE$id, visit = MIE$visit, room = MIE$room, timepoint = MIE$timepoint, value = MIE$value)
}
length.LongitudinalData <- function(a) {
  b <- unique(a@subject) %>%
    length
  b
}
x <- make_LD(MIE)
print(class(x))
print(x)
```

Thanks for any help, please let me know if there's anything else I should include.